# Plot occurrences over time in R from a dataset of H:M:S timestamps

Tags: r, plot, timeline

I'm trying to plot, essentially, a timeline. I have two lists of timestamps in %H:%M:%S format, and I want to show them as occurrences over an x-axis of continuous time from 0 to 8 minutes.
Everything I can find is either a specialized package for a timeline that bins data by year instead of showing it continuously scatterplot style, or it requires a y-axis. I'm not plotting a function, so I don't have a y-axis, just two lines made up of dots something like this: [mock excel plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EezdU.jpg). I got this by putting in fake values for the missing axis. It's also vertical instead of horizontal, but that's easily fixed. 
I'm trying to show all the times in those 8 minutes a person pronounced an S and all the times she deleted it so I can see if she starts deleting more as time goes on.

Edit: here's some of my data as requested.

```
s deleted s pronounced
0:02:32 0:00:49
0:04:01 0:00:50
0:04:02 0:00:51
0:04:10 0:00:56
0:04:11 0:00:58
0:04:44 0:00:59
0:05:59 0:01:09
0:06:03 0:01:10
0:06:31 0:01:12
0:06:33 0:05:59
0:06:40 0:06:00
        0:06:06
        0:06:06
        0:06:32
        0:06:43
        0:06:44
        0:06:47
        0:06:51
        0:06:52
        0:07:10
        0:07:14
```

Comment: To get better help, post either a small snippet of your data or simulate the data in actual R code. Posting a link to a picture of something you made in Excel does not help very much.

Comment: Is that better?